# OutOfMemory Exception while using FileBody for sending images to the server in Android?

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

I am using FileBody for sending images to the server from Android. But when sending bigger images the application crashes with OutOfMemory exception.

Is there some way of overcoming this? Or has anyone faced the same problem with FileBody.

Please help me out in this regard.

Regards

Sunil

Comment: Would using a ByteBody help? Example http://code.google.com/p/ou-android/source/browse/trunk/Where-android/src/net/sylvek/where/FacebookClient.java?r=56

Comment: how many bytes can be send at a time or how many bytes should be send at a time so that this exception doesnt occur.